# Remove empty strings of array of string in C

Tags: arrays, c, string

I made a program that reads the output from a text file line by line and puts it into an array. So I got an array of strings.

The problem arises when I go through that array of strings and check if those strings meet certain conditions. When I form an array of strings that meet a certain condition, I get empty lines as array elements.

For Example:

Expressions in a text file:

```
X&Y
X|Y
!X
(X|Y)|Z
(X&Y)|Z
(X&Y)&Z
(X&Y)|Z&(A|B
((X|Y)|Z)&((A|B)|(C&D))
(X&Y)|(Z&(A|B))
(A|B)&(!C)
A|(B&(C&(D|E)))
((X|Y)|(Z&(A|B)))|((C&D)&(D|E))
(A|B)|(C&D)&(D|E)
!A&(B|C)
(A|B)|(C|D)&(D
!A|(B&C)
```

When I print a new array of strings whose elements meet a certain condition, I get empty lines as elements.

```
X&Y
X|Y
!X
(X|Y)|Z
(X&Y)|Z
(X&Y)&Z
         //Here
((X|Y)|Z)&((A|B)|(C&D))
(X&Y)|(Z&(A|B))
(A|B)&(!C)
A|(B&(C&(D|E)))
((X|Y)|(Z&(A|B)))|((C&D)&(D|E))
(A|B)|(C&D)&(D|E)
!A&(B|C)
         //Here
```

Some elements that should be printed are not printed because of those empty lines? Can someone help me remove these empty lines?

Here's code:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *dat;
    int number_of_elements;
    char str[MAX][MAXLEN];
    int NumberOfRightBracket=0;
    int NumberOFLeftBracket=0;
    int NumberOfOperators=0;
    int Number=0;
    int i=0;
    char g[200][MAXLEN];
    dat=fopen("dat.txt","r");
    if(dat==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
    }
    while(!feof(dat) && !ferror(dat))
    {
        if(fgets(str[i],100,dat)!=NULL)
        str[i][strcspn(str[i],"\n")] = 0;

        char p[100];
        strcpy(p,str[i]);

        for(int o=0;o<strlen(p);o++)
        {
            if(p[o]=='(')
                NumberOfLeftBracket++;
            else if(p[o]==')')
                NumberOfRightBracket++;
            else if(p[o]=='*' || p[o]=='|' || p[o]=='&' || p[o]=='!')
                NumberOfOperators++;
        }


        if(NumberOfRightBracket!=0 && NumberOfLeftBracket!=0 && NumberOfRightBracket==NumberOfLeftBracket)
        {
           strcpy(g[i],p);
           Number++;

        }
        else if(NumberOfRightBracket==0 && NumberOfLeftBracket==0 && NumberOfOperators==1)
        {
            strcpy(g[i],p);

            Number++;

        }

        NumberOfRightBracket=0;
        NumberOfLeftBracket=0;
        NumberOfOperators=0;
        i++;
    }

   for(int k=0;k<Number;k++)
   {
     printf("%s\n",g[k];
   }

}
```

Comment: When `fgets` does return `NULL` you just carry on. You can replace the complicated loop controls with `while(fgets(str[i], MAXLEN, dat) != NULL)`

Comment: Aside: instead of resetting the three counters `NumberOfRightBracket` etc at the end of the loop, do it at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: Another: why do you need a 2d array `char str[MAX][MAXLEN];`? You never go back to revisit a previous string.

Comment: You can change `strcpy(g[i],p);` to `strcpy(g[Number],p);` (in both places) to get rid of the empty lines. (But they were not really empty, they were uninitialized.)

Comment: The code in the question has two typos that prevent it from compiling. So we know it is not the code you executed. Edit the question to provide a [mre], including **exactly** the code that demonstrates the problem, and **all** of the code, including `#include` and `#define` directives.

Comment: @Andew Tayloe `strcpy(p,str[i]);` is a problem when `fgets()` returns `NULL` - avoid that UB and exit the loop instead.

Comment: `while(!feof(dat) && !ferror(dat)) {  if(fgets(str[i],100,dat)!=NULL)` --> `while(fgets(str[i], sizeof str[i], dat)) {`

Comment: Note: `dat=fopen("dat.txt","r"); if(dat==NULL) { printf("Error"); }` is dangerous.  If the file can't be opened, you print part of a message to `stdout`, but continue as if the file was opened.  You should report errors on `stderr`; you should end messages with a newline; you should include the filename in the error message; you should not use a literal filename when calling `fopen()` — it should be a variable so you can easily include the filename in the message; you should exit with a failure status (`exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`) or otherwise not continue.  You might report the system error too.

Comment: It's clean and tidy if you close the files you open before exiting.  In a `main()` function that immediately exits, it isn't harmful, but if you make the code into a function that is called with many files (eg command-line arguments), then you leak resources which is a bad idea.  Get into the good habits now!

Answer (score 0):

You use `i` to decide where in `g` to store each line from the input, and `i` is incremented in every iteration, but you use `Number` to count the number of retained strings, and you only increment `Number` when retaining a string.

The result is various `g[i]` where you decided not to retain a string never get updated with data from a line, but you do print them.

You do not need both `i` and `Number`. Use just one variable to keep track of both how many lines you have so far and where to put the next line in `g`.

(You also do not need `g` if the program is only supposed to do what it appears to be currently attempting.)